# About the sequence $a_n=\{\pi^n\}$

Tags: analysis

Is the sequence $\{\pi^n\}=\pi^n-\lfloor\pi^n\rfloor$ dense? In other words for any given $\varepsilon>0$ and $t\in[0,1]$ is there a proper $n\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $|\{\pi^n\}-t|<\varepsilon$ ?

(*) What is the condition on $q$ to make the sequence $\{q^n\}$ dense?

I know the necessary and sufficient condition for $\{nq\}$ is $q\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Also, to make the question * nicer, extend it for all (positive and negative) integers.

Comment: @Peter he knows about $nq$ and asks about $q^n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You are right. I have not read carefully.

Answer (score 5):

For $(\ast)$ see [Power Fractional Parts](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerFractionalParts.html)  and the references there. [Hardy and Littlewood (1914)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485887375) proved that the sequence of fractional parts $q^n-\lfloor q^n\rfloor$  is equidistributed for almost all real numbers $q>1$. One exceptional number is the golden ratio. I don't know if $\pi$ is another exception, probably not. I did not find a specific result about $\pi$. I think that it is an open problem.

Comment: well, and what about (specifically) $\pi$? The statement you cite shows that it is very likely for $\pi$ to have that property, but is it known to be true in this specific case?

Comment: @Thomas I am afraid that there is a reason why the MW reference makes no mention of $\pi$ provably having that property

Comment: I am looking thorough the references, but I did not find a specific result about $\pi$.

Comment: ah, an open problem then ;-)