# Can $\ e^n\ $ be arbitrarily close to an integer , if $\ n\ $ is a positive integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For a positive integer $\ n\ $ , define $\ x:=e^n\ $ and $\ y\ $ the number we get if we round $x$ correctly to the next integer.

> Can $\ |x-y|\ $ get arbitrarily small ? In other words, are there better and better "near"-integers of the form $\ e^n\ $ with positive integers $\ n\ $ ?

The smallest value up to $\ n=10^4\ $ occurs for $\ n=5469\ $ with fractional part $\ 0.000029\cdots $

If we could show that the set {$frac(e^n)\mid n\in \mathbb N$} is dense in $\ [0,1]\ $ , this would answer my question. Can we do that ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2761380/299698 Especially the linked paper by G. H. Hardy and J. E. Littlewood.

Comment: Very hard to guess a reason for this downvote

Comment: @Peter Harder still when since then, there have been at least seven upvotes.